# Removing jre7 installs jre6

Tags: linux-mint, java

I am working under Mint 16 and I want to remove jre7 packages (`openjdk-7-jre`, `openjdk-7-jre-lib` and `openjdk-7-jre-headless`) since I don't need them anymore.

Using synaptic or apt-get I can easily get rid of them, but it installs jre6 associated packages instead. And when I try to uninstall jre6 packages, I installs back jre7 ones.

I have tried using `--no-download` and `--no-install-recommends` but it didn't did the trick.

I don't really understand what's going on. Why can't I remove these packages ? Is there a way to achieve this operation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at which packages depend on `openjdk-7-jre` being instaleld and use

```
 apt-rdepends -r openjdk-7-jre
```

to remove these together with the openjdk-7-jre.

You might however find this impractical, I once thought I could get rid of of Java and Perl on a Linux server machine and couldn't without expecting to break the system.

Comment: I see now -- I have a Java program (I thought it was Qt C++) that needs these packages. Though, I thought apt-get will remove it rather than installing an older jre.